# jekyll url not working on github

Tags: html, jekyll

Hello Stack Oerflow community,

Can somebody maybe explain to me why the following code is working local, but not on github?
Everything is outputted like it should, except for the background-image.
Hope to hear from you.

Greetings

Wim

the HTML

```
    <div class="thumb_container">

        {% for project in site.data.settings.home %}
            <div class="thumb-holder">

            <a href="{{ project.link}}"><div class="thumb-unit" style="background-image:  url(/assets/img/home/{{ project.folder}}/thumb.jpg)"><h3>{{ project.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{ project.text}}</p>
            </div></a>

            </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

And this is the YML

```
# Thumb Section

home:
- {folder: 'thumb_1', name: 'Chaffee', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de  chaffee', link: 'chaffee.html'}
- {folder: 'thumb_2', name: 'Greyhound', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de greyhound' }
- {folder: 'thumb_3', name: 'M2 Half-Track', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_4', name: 'M3 scout car', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_5', name: 'Brencarrier', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_6', name: 't34/85', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_7', name: 'SD-KZF 251', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_8', name: 'Englisch bikes', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_9', name: 'Dodge staffcar', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_10', name: 'Harley', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_11', name: 'MIG 17', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_12', name: 'Willeys', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_13', name: 'Hummer', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_14', name: 'Ferret', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_15', name: 'Korps mariniers', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
- {folder: 'thumb_16', name: 'museum', text: 'Hier komt tekst over de halftrack' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're GitHub page URL is in the following pattern, the  (**absolute**) path would be wrong:

```
http://myusername.github.com/my-repo/
+
/assets/img/home/{{ project.folder}}/thumb.jpg
=
http://myusername.github.com/assets/img/home/{{ project.folder}}/thumb.jpg
```

So the (**relative**) path should be one of these:

```
../assets/img/home/{{ project.folder}}/thumb.jpg
./assets/img/home/{{ project.folder}}/thumb.jpg
```

To receive this uri:

```
http://myusername.github.com/my-repo/assets/img/home/{{ project.folder}}/thumb.jpg
```

Comment: I found it, this is working: assets/img/home/{{ project.folder}}/thumb.jpg Thanks for your help Fabio!

Comment: `assets/img/home/{{ project.folder}}/thumb.jpg` works the same as `./assets/img/home/{{ project.folder}}/thumb.jpg`. If you're question is answered, don't forget to accept it.